# Is there a way to stop USB devices from triggering Android activity's pause/resume cycle?

Tags: android-activity, android-usb

The following is in AndroidManifest.xml for MainActivity:

```
   <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/usb_device_filter" />
    </activity>
```

If I plug in USB devices A, B, and C for the first time, the OS prompts me to select the app. This is exactly what it should be. After I unplug all of them, then plug them back, MainActivity pauses and resumes three times (i.e., pauses and resumes, and in a fraction of a second, pauses and resumes again, then in a faction of a second, pauses and resumes for the last time). The app is always in the foreground.

This is not a huge problem. It is manageable. I am curious if there is a way to avoid this kind of useless pause/resume cycle when the app is already in the foreground.

Answer (score 1):

**Potential Solution**:

With no way to test, here is one possible reason this could be happening.

You are running with launchMode as 'singleInstance'. It is possible that the three pause-resume cycles you experience when plugging the three usb devices back are three restart cycles.

Try setting

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

[Documentation singleTop](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element)

> If an instance of the activity already exists at the top of the target task, the system routes the intent to that instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new instance of the activity.

My reasoning is that singleTop might specifically route the newIntent to the already running instance. It's one possible solution, given the information we have available.

Comment: Thank you for lending a hand. The app currently uses android:launchMode="singleInstance". I have just read the document and found it is supposed to invoke onNewIntent() too. It seems that onReume() always follows onNewIntent(). I think I may use onNewIntent() as a flag to help manage this situation.

Comment: Good deal. If I think of anything else though I'll share.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can stop it. but you can use a broadcast receiver to detect the attached / detached event and take action from there.

(disclaimer untested)

```
private final BroadcastReceiver usbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {
            // USB device attached, handle it
        } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
            // USB device detached, handle it
        }
    }
};
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. The app already has the receiver to handle the attachments and detachments. I just hope the the life cycle is not triggered by these events when the app is already at the top.

Comment: yeah sorry the only way I could see it working is to handle the specific action type for onResume, maybe a return false if the action is usb_device is enough to do the trick?